# How to write SQL queries that randomly select questions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following queries that randomly select a question from a database for a quiz game

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
    questionsbank
WHERE QuestionID <> 1
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
```

However, when an user answer a question correctly then I have to randomly select another question different from the one just selected and it keeps continue. How would I do that in sql? My thoughts is to declare a variable and the push the QuestionID that has been answered and then use the NOT IN statement but I don't know how to implement that.

Comment: `WHERE QuestionID NOT IN(1, 2, 4, 10 [,...]`   ...  Should do the trick.

Comment: Your code is correct, order by a random number and pick only one. To exclude already choosen questions, your suggestion is also correct, exclude those ids in subsequent queries with a not in or similar.

Comment: I would start with a table that has one row for each question that a user answers correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Well my guess is at some moment you will have to save the user answer on the db.

so if you have the table:

```
Answers (answer_id (pk), user_id (fk), question_id  (fk), answer ...);
```

You can filter the question already answer like this:

```
 SELECT Q.*
 FROM QuestionsBank Q
 LEFT JOIN Answers A
   ON Q.question_id = A.question_id
  AND A.user_id = @yourUser
WHERE A.question_id is NULL
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```